# CSS to create a "Loading" flashing Skeleton gray box (FOUC, Flash of Unstyled Content)

Tags: html, css

To indicate that different parts of the screen are loading, we want to implement a FOUC-type flashing gray box. Surprisingly, all the resources on the web are about how to remove or get rid of FOUC content, not how to simulate it. How would I create an FOUC-type "flashing gray cover" for any particular `<div>` in CSS?

The requirements are, (1) this CSS must obscure any inner content, (2) it must animate 2-3 gray colors including `#F5F5F5`.

I have a starting point in this snippet, but it doesn't obscure any content or animate. Where do I go from here?

```css
.infoColumns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.flashLoading {
     /* Should obscure all content and flash similar gray colors */
     background-color: #F5F5F5
}
```

```html
<div class="infoColumns">
   <p>Item 1:</p>
   <p class="flashLoading">Value for Item 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe what you are talking about is called a skeleton in UI terms.
You can steal the css from Material UI
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-skeleton/

Comment: Good callout. But since that code isn't readily available (I checked the link), and we're not using Material UI, it would still be a good idea to provide a complete answer in this thread, for the benefit of everyone searching.

Comment: color: transparent in addition to the background?

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off topic here. Please see the [help].

Comment: It's an actual question, and not an off-site request, so let's focus on the technical question at hand. For clarity I rephrased it.

Comment: @geneb. I believe you can just inspect their code via devtools for the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: (1) define the main `skeleton` style as below, with transparent text, and then (2) `keyframes` for it to alternate from  0 to 100%:

```
.skeleton {
    animation: skeleton-loading 1s linear infinite alternate;
    color: transparent;
}

@keyframes skeleton-loading {
    0% {
        background-color: #F5F5F5; /* FROM Color 1 */
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #E2E2E2; /* TO Color 2 */
    }
}
```

```css
.infoColumns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.skeleton {
    animation: skeleton-loading 1s linear infinite alternate;
    color: transparent;
}

@keyframes skeleton-loading {
    0% {
        background-color: #F5F5F5; /* FROM Color 1 */
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #E2E2E2; /* TO Color 2 */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="infoColumns">
   <p>Item 1:</p>
   <p class="skeleton">Value for Item 1</p>
</div>
```